# remove Cookie using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two cookies in my JS file and I want to remove them.

I have tried the code below but it is not working

```
 $.removeCookie('filter', { path: '/Home/' });
 $.removeCookie('Pfilter', { path: '/Home/' });
```

I have also tried the below for null cookies, but this is also not working.

Thanks for the help

```
$.cookie('filter',null, { path: '/Home/' });
```

Comment: Have you included the cookie plugin? jQuery has no `cookie` and `removeCookie` methods by default.

Answer (score 48):

It might depend on what path your cookie is using. If you goto the chrome developer tools and check the path column under Resources > Cookies > Path.

[image]

You might be using the generic `/` for your path instead of `/Home/`. Give the code below a try.

To delete a cookie with jQuery set the value to null:

```
$.removeCookie('filter', { path: '/' });
```

Comment: i am using the specific page eg. Home page so use the Home in that

Comment: Did you check the chrome developer tools? Resources > Cookies > Path?

Comment: It also possibly need to specify `domain` like `{ domain: '.stackoverflow.com' }`, this in pair with `path` solve my problem.

Comment: Learnt something new today. Thanks... Never knew this was available.

Comment: @Mark This answer is awesome!

Answer (score 7):

Did you try 
$.cookie("name", null);

```
$.removeCookie('filter', { path: '/' });
```

Comment: thanks @Ravia for the hint... it worked awesome! should be marked as answer

Answer (score 3):

What works for me is setting the cookie to null before removing it: 

`$.cookie("filter", null);
$.removeCookie("filter);`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with jquery version 1.7.1 and jquery cookie version 1.4.1

This was driving me crazy so I decided to dive into the source code and I figured out what is wrong.

Here is the definition of $.removeCookie

```
$.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
    if ($.cookie(key) === undefined) { // this line is the problem
        return false;
    }

    // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
    $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
    return !$.cookie(key);
};
```

As you can see when the function checks if the cookie exists it doesn't take the options object into account. So if you are on a different path than the cookie you're trying to remove the function will fail.

A Few Solutions:

Upgrade Jquery Cookies. The most recent version doesn't even do that sanity check.

or add this to you document ready

```
$.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
    if ($.cookie(key, options) === undefined) { // this line is the fix
        return false;
    }

    // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
    $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
    return !$.cookie(key);
};
```

or when removing cookies do something like this:

```
$.cookie('cookie-name', '', { path: '/my/path', expires:-1 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a domain parameter when creating a cookie, this will work

```
$.removeCookie('cookie', { path: '/' , domain  : 'yourdomain.com'});
```

Comment: This works for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This simple way it works fine:

```
$.cookie("cookieName", "", { expires: -1 });
```