# Deleting two cookies on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

When a user clicks a link on my page (which has the class `deleteCooke`), I want to run a function which deleted two cookies.

The `href` itself will control the redirect so just want to delete (or clear) the two cookies.

These two cookies are: `lang` and `category`.

**Here is my current approach:**

```js
/* 1. GET CURRENT COOKIE VALUE */
var lang = $.cookie('lang');
var category = $.cookie('category');

/* 2. DELETE FUNCTION*/
function deleteCookies() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  window.document.cookie = lang + "=" + "; " + expires;
  window.document.cookie = category + "=" + "; " + expires;
}

/* 3. CALL FUNCTION ON BUTTON CLICK*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deleteLang").click(function() {
    deleteCookies();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<a href="/" class="deleteLang" data-lang="es">Espanyol</a>
```

However, with this approach, neither of the cookies are being cleared / deleted?

**Edit**:

How cookie is being set

```
$.cookie('lang', 'es', {expires: 2, path: '/'});
```

Current method of removing cookies

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".deleteLang").click(function() {
     $.removeCookie('lang', { path: '/' });
     $.removeCookie('lang', '', {expires: 2, path: '/'});
     $.removeCookie('lang'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: You seem to be using `jquery.cookie` so why not just do this: `$.removeCookie('buyLang', { path: '/' });`?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen - I have tried something equivalent to that before and it didn't work. I've just tried: `$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".deleteLang").click(function() {
     $.removeCookie('lang', { path: '/' });
     $.removeCookie('category', { path: '/' });
  });
});` and it still didn't clear the cookie?

Comment: Did you set it using a path?  Have you tried unsetting it just using the name and not including the path?

Comment: @Pete - I've just updated my question to show how the cookie is set and the latest approach

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486165/remove-cookie-using-jquery-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<a href="/" class="deleteLang" data-lang="es">Espanyol</a>

$.cookie('lang', 'es', {expires: 2, path: '/'});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deleteLang").click(function(e) {
    // Prevent navigation.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check if the cookie is set
    console.log($.cookie('lang'));

    // Cookie is removed if 'true' is returned.
    console.log($.removeCookie('lang', { path: '/' }));

    // Check that cookie is 'undefined'.
    console.log($.cookie('lang'));
  });
});
```

If you check the console you'll see:

```
es
true
undefined
```

just as expected.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnpoje94/1/)